# How to read Ionic2 map object in ionic2?

Tags: json, object, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to fetch a object in `ionic2` which has key value and i want to read the **key** and the **brand name** from it within `ionic2`.

so my question :

**how i can read the key from the below object** ?

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "products": {
        "Key1": [
            {
              "entity_id": "448",
              "sku": "587",
              "name": "name",
              "image_url": "587.png",
              "price": "15,000",
              "qty": 0,
              "rating": 0,
              "wishlist": false,
              "specialprice": "7,500",
              "brand": "brandname"
            }
        ],
        "Key2": [
            {
              "entity_id": "448",
              "sku": "587",
              "name": "name",
              "image_url": "587.png",
              "price": "15,000",
              "qty": 0,
              "rating": 0,
              "wishlist": false,
              "specialprice": "7,500",
              "brand": "brandname"
            }
        ],
        "Key3": [
            {
              "entity_id": "448",
              "sku": "587",
              "name": "name",
              "image_url": "587.png",
              "price": "15,000",
              "qty": 0,
              "rating": 0,
              "wishlist": false,
              "specialprice": "7,500",
              "brand": "brandname"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

please feel free to help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're variable which contains this is called `data`.

`data.products` will return the list of products. (or 'Key's in your case.)

Then calling `data.products.Key1` will give you the object of `Key1`.

`data.products.Key1.entity_id` will return '448'.

So logically you can get the brandname by calling `data.prodcuts.Key1.brand`

**Edit** misread:

Since your `Key1` is a list for some reason.

`data.products.Key1[0].brand`

Comment: thank you for your response but the`key1` and all other `key` i want to get dynamically any suggestion ?

Comment: Taken from https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/15 it says you can use `for(let key of data.products)` but I haven't tested myself